# Way to make PDF of a Storyboard in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there an easy way to make a PDF or image file (png / jpg / jpeg) of a full storyboard in Xcode 4.3 to export and send to someone else or post a question on this forum?  I would just make a screenshot, but my storyboard is way too big for my monitor and I'd rather not have to manually paste it back together in an image editing program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's no "Export storyboard to PDF" option in xcode, but I know this:
Double-clicking on the storyboard file name opens it in it's own window. Then you can go full screen with it, and right click to zoom out to your desired scale.

[image]

You can then either drag a box to select everything or hit Command + A. Every view including the segues can then be dragged around as on unit.

[image]

Other than that, I think your out of luck. And if you need to see all of the details of each view, I would take screenshots either in the simulator or the device itself. Then add your connections in whatever editing software you use to make the mockup storyboard.

A quick Photoshop tip for doing that would be the line tool with automatic arrows at the beginning or end. You just draw a line, and it sticks an arrowhead at the end. done. You can access that option from the little arrow dropdown with the line tool active.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could go fullscreen like that. Too bad there's isn't an easier way, but you've made it pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Retina Mac, how can switch the Screen to the highest possible resolution (e.g. with SwitchResX 3360*2100) and make a screenshot. This is sufficient for the most smaller Storyboards

Answer (score -1):

I'd really like to be able to export a storyboard to PDF too, even though a storyboard isn't great for a wireframe it would be a good starting point for discussions without having to make it all from scratch.

The only option I've found that comes close is the fact you can copy a view (view controller and segues etc. unfortunately) and then paste it into Photoshop, Pages etc.