# How to take screen shot of Storyboard project flow?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode4.5

I was wondering is there any way to capture the Storyboard full view in XCode with good resolution SO that one can understand the project flow in one run.
I try to capture with the windows+shift+4+space but is wasn't so good and become blurry when zoom in.

Comment: capture  multiple screenshot and convert into one :)

Answer (score 4):

To date, there is no really good solution for this task, but one of these answers may help:

1. [XCode: Export Storyboard to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013810/xcode-export-storyboard-to-image)
2. [Way to make PDF of a Storyboard in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469840/way-to-make-pdf-of-a-storyboard-in-xcode)